# Drop 4 first columns

Tags: unix, awk, split

I have a command that can drop first 4 columns, but unfortunately if 2nd column name and 4th column name likely similar, it will truncate at 2nd column but if 2nd column and 4th column name are not same it will truncate at 4th column. Is it anything wrong to my commands?

**

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {h=substr($0, index($0,$5)); next} 
                {file= path ""$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_03042017.csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "DETAILS 03042017" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$5)) > file} 
                 END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' filename
```

**

```
Input:

 Account Num  | Name | Card_Holder_Premium | Card_Holder| Type_Card | Balance | Date_Register  
 01  | 02   | 03    | 04     | 05    | 06  | 07


  Output

_Premium | Card_Holder| Type_Card | Balance | Date_Register 
04 | 05    | 06  | 07

 My desired output:

Card_Holder| Type_Card | Balance | Date_Register
 05  | 06  |07
```

Comment: How is that awk script related to removing 4 columns? Did you maybe post the wrong script?

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question instead of changing conditions?

Answer (score 4):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ sed -E 's/([^|]+\| ){4}//' file
April | May | June
05    | 06  | 07

$ awk '{sub(/([^|]+\| ){4}/,"")}1' file
April | May | June
05    | 06  | 07
```

Comment: I want to make sure that the column drop at first 4 columns. @EdMorton

Comment: @Jiji: Assuming by that you mean "drop the first 4 columns": That's exactly what these commands do, based on your sample input.

Comment: @mklement0 ya youre right. but i have problem if my 2nd column and 4th column is likely same

Comment: @Jiji: If you're going strictly by column _index_, that doesn't matter, however. Your code tries to use `index()` to find the character offset of field `$5` in the whole line, which _could_ match an earlier field, but that's not the case with your sample input. Please update your question with  a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jiji sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to say. Please edit your question to show us.

Comment: @mklement0 ya its affecting if 2nd column and 4th column likely same/ I try already..it will cut 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

The method you use to remove columns using index is not correct. As you have figured out, index can be confused and match the previous field when the previous field contains the same words as the next field.

The correct way is the one advised by Ed Morton.

[In this online test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcllDcEdMRkt6VnM), bellow code based on Ed Morton suggestion, gives you the output you expect:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {sub(/([^|]+\|){3}/,"");h=$0;next} \
{file=$1$2"_"$3"_"$4"_03042017.csv"; sub(/([^|]+\|){3}/,""); \
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAILS 03042017" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} \
END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' file1.csv

#Output
DETAILS 03042017
 Card_Holder| Type_Card | Balance | Date_Register
 04     | 05    | 06  | 07
EOF 1
```

Due to the whitespace that you have include in your fields, the filename of the generated file appears as `01   02   _ 03    _ 04     _03042017.csv`. With your real data this filename should appear correct.

In any case, i just adapt Ed Morton answer to your code. If you are happy with this solution you should accept Ed Morton answer.

PS: I just removed a space from Ed Morton answer since it seems to work a bit better with your not so clear data.

Ed Suggested:

```
awk '{sub(/([^|]+\| ){4}/,"")}1' file
#Mind this space   ^
```

This space here it might fail to catch your data if there is no space after each field (i.e `April|May`).

On the other hand, by removing this space it seems that Ed Solution can correctly match either fields in format `April  |  May` or in format `April|May`

Comment: @EdMorton Ed, Is it ok to remove this extra space from your code?

Comment: Thanks but just leave it as I don't think the OP has told us what his real question is or real data looks like yet. I don't believe his real data looks the way he's currently showing it in his question so no point massaging answers to make them work on it.